# Using something else than IN for subquery mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i'm writing a query that uses an insert and an update the update has a subquery which selects one or multiple rows.
When I run the query I get the following error: "#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"

The strange thing is that I am using the latest version of mysql and this feature was supported since 5.1. My query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Orders 
    (OrderID, Orderdate, Leverdate, status) 
    VALUES ('', now(), '2014-21-05', 'In      Behandeling');

UPDATE Dozen SET OrderID = LAST_INSERT_ID() 
    WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT DoosID FROM Dozen Limit 0,3);
```

How can I rewrite this query to something mysql will understand and execute?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you change the IN to =, because the subquery only returns 1 result?

Comment: as @pascalvgemert said, there's no reason to use IN as you're only returning one row and column

Comment: The one row is just an example, maybe a bad one but ok. In my php version the "1" is a variable

Answer (score 0):

use `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE Dozen 
INNER JOIN Orders ON DoosID = OrderID
SET Dozen.OrderID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Or change **IN** into **=** since your subquery anyways returns 1 record.

```
UPDATE Dozen 
SET OrderID = LAST_INSERT_ID()
WHERE OrderID = (SELECT DoosID FROM Dozen LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: This is really close, I would go with your first option because LIMIT will not always be 1. Problem is the ON clause. DoosID is not stored in the table Orders in my design because if you have multiple DoosID's for one order ID you will have duplicate data in your table. I can't have multiple rows with the same orderID